# Download blob in downloadLink

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to download application/pdf in downloadLink. Is it possible? What is the simplest way to download file as pdf. I have base64string.

```
    const binaryString = window.atob(this.base64ToDisplay);    
    const len = binaryString.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const fileName = 'example.pdf';
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = blob;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
```

How to download this file?

Comment: Why are you doing this as base64!?  It's binary...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private downloadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        // create blob and build an URL
        let blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = url;

        // append url to element and trigger click
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', PDF_FILE_NAME);
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();

        // clean up
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead of `Blob` as `href` attribute.

```js
const bytes = 'abcdef';
const blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
downloadLink.download = 'document.pdf';
downloadLink.click();
```

Comment: I did it but unfortunetely nothing is downloading :|

Comment: @SixtySeven It works, check out by clicking "Run code snippet".